# How to play mp3 from & to specific time in milliseconds on iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer

I have a requirement to play mp3 from and to specific time [given in milliseconds].
After some research my bet went on AVPlayer, which seems to be the choice for everyone with similar requirement.
Unfortunately for me it doesn't work [code included at the end].
I am wondering if there's anything else I could use to play any iOS supported file format with start & stop specified using milliseconds timescale?

Here's my code using AVPlayer. I have created an mp3 which at 4.3 seconds has silence for around 600ms and then noise for around a second.
I have 3 options of creating CMTime for use with seekToTime:

- 4300 value with 1000 timescale
- 4.3 * 60000 with 60000 timescale
- 4.3 * timescale of the mp3 file with timescale of the mp3 file.

Unfortunately none of the options worked for me, it was always set to somewhere inside the noise.

I've tried to use lower values, just for the sake of it.
I got to 3.7 seconds, which when set, starts a little bit BEFORE the silence.
Funny thing: if I use 3.75 it will start to play in the middle of the noise.

**Crucial parts of the code:**

Declaration of CMTime:

```
mediaAudioStart = CMTimeMake((int64_t) (floatValue * 60000), 60000);
```

or

```
int32_t timeScale = _mediaAudioPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale;
mediaAudioStart = CMTimeMake((int64_t) (floatValue * timeScale), timeScale);
```

or

```
mediaAudioStart = CMTimeMake(4300, 1000);
```

**Full code**

Usage of seekToTime:

```
[_mediaAudioPlayer seekToTime:mediaAudioStart toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mediaAudioPlaybackFinished) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
            NSLog(@"CURRENT TIME: %lld", _mediaAudioPlayer.currentTime.value);
            [_mediaAudioPlayer play];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Could not seek media overlay file.");
        }
    }];
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareMediaAudio {
    NSLog(@"prepareMediaAudio");
    NSString *mediaAudioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boostmiddle" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *mediaAudioURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:mediaAudioPath];
    if (!_mediaAudioPlayer) {
        AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:mediaAudioURL];
        [self setMediaAudioPlayer:player];
        [_mediaAudioPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
    } else {
        [self mediaAudioSeek];
    }
}

- (void)stopMediaAudio {
    NSLog(@"stopMediaAudio");
    if (_mediaAudioPlayer) {
        [_mediaAudioPlayer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
        [_mediaAudioPlayer pause];
        _mediaAudioPlayer = nil;
    }
}

- (void)mediaAudioSeek {
    NSLog(@"mediaAudioSeek %lld %d", mediaAudioStart.value, mediaAudioStart.timescale);

    [_mediaAudioPlayer seekToTime:mediaAudioStart toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mediaAudioPlaybackFinished) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
            NSLog(@"CURRENT TIME: %lld", _mediaAudioPlayer.currentTime.value);
            [_mediaAudioPlayer play];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Could not seek media overlay file.");
        }
    }];
}

- (void)mediaAudioPlaybackFinished {
    NSLog(@"mediaAudioPlaybackFinished");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
    [self stopMediaAudio];
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"observeValueForKeyPath");
    if (object == _mediaAudioPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (_mediaAudioPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"READY TO PLAY");
        } else if (_mediaAudioPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"Could not load Media Overlay audio");
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)button1Action:(id)sender {
    NSString *value = valueText.text;
    float floatValue = [value floatValue];
    NSLog(@"button1Action %f", floatValue);
    mediaAudioStart = CMTimeMake((int64_t) (floatValue * 60000), 60000);
    [self mediaAudioSeek];
}

- (IBAction)button2Action:(id)sender {
    NSString *value = valueText.text;
    float floatValue = [value floatValue];
    NSLog(@"button2Action %f", floatValue);
    int32_t timeScale = _mediaAudioPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale;
    mediaAudioStart = CMTimeMake((int64_t) (floatValue * timeScale), timeScale);
    [self prepareMediaAudio];
}

- (IBAction)button3Action:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button3Action [4300, 1000]");
    mediaAudioStart = CMTimeMake(4300, 1000);
    [self prepareMediaAudio];
}

- (IBAction)stopAction:(id)sender {
    [self stopMediaAudio];
}

- (IBAction)prepareAction:(id)sender {
    [self prepareMediaAudio];
}
```

**Example project**

You can get my project from here, including the mp3 file I use for testing. Just type 4.3 in the text field.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7q2xmuhdu1xih75/iosAudioTest.zip?dl=0

**EDIT:**

After updating the mp3 file - making it shorter - the values used to get to the same spot changed. Now 4.3 points to somewhere else :/ Now I'm totally clueless regarding operation of the seekToTime method.

Answer (score 1):

https://warrenmoore.net/understanding-cmtime

The above post has the clearest description of CMTime I have come across. You are interpreting it wrong I'm afraid. If you want to jump 4.3 seconds in you need a CMTime of (4.3, 60000) where 4.3 is the number of seconds and 60000 is the precision you need for each second.

```
[av_player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(4.3, 60000) toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
```

will give you a CMTime set to 4.3 seconds which has a precision of 60000 - meaning you can jump to any one of 60000 different positions between each second of time.

Comment: thanks, I read that page, and it seems to be linked in every question regarding `seekToTime`, however `CMTimeMake` takes `int64_t` (which is `long long`), and not `float`, so it would be converted to 4, which makes no sense. if `floatValue` is set to 4.3, it will be passed as 4, it will be divided by `timescale` (60000 in your example) and this value will be used as start, which makes it almost the beginning of the file. I've tried that with my test project and the sound is played from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry Krystian - should have re-read the docs. CMTimeMakeWithSeconds is the method. I've changed the answer.

Comment: amergin: Thanks, but I'm afraid that the difference between the two approaches are ALMOST none. I get more or less the same result. The silence which should start at 4.3 starts at 3.6. I have no idea where is this offset coming from. Again if I change the length of the file, the values required to "hit" the silence change as well.

Comment: Have you tried with a different track? Every now and then I come across audio files that have incorrect metadata like encoded at 44.1k but metadata showing 48k

Comment: Yeah, besides I was doing the encoding multiple times using Audacity, checked it using other tools, and the timescale reported by AVPlayerItem is indeed 44.100.

Comment: Downloaded your project, imported the mp3 into GarageBand then re-exported it. Tried it in your project and it works fine. I think your problem is maybe Audacity.

Comment: Perfect one..! Thank you for saving my day..!